# Marquee text in EditText box?

Tags: android, android-edittext, marquee

How can I set the marquee property for the text in my EditText box?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

marquee is only for textview, I don't think you can make it work in EditText. The other option you have is to use a textview and then convert it to an edittext when user clicks on it for entry. Later when it loses focus, take the text replace it in the same textview and hide the edit text.

Comment: I really like answers like this. More on the concept/thought. Instead of providing code. It leaves the reader space to think on how to implement the concept provided. +1